# Random images from array without repeating

Tags: c#

using:

```
Image[] icons = { image12, image9, image11, image12, image10, image9, image11, image1,  image12, image9, image11, image10, image12, image9, image10, image11, image9, image10, image12, image11 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        newicon[i] = icons[rnd.Next(0, 19)];
    }
```

I am attempting to take the list of "icons" and scramble them without repeating them

basically I need 
1 image1, 5 image9, 4 image10, 5 image11, and 5 image12's to output, But no more than that amount of each. Everything I have tried ends up with more other images and no image1 or multiple image1's.

I have done this with numbers, which tends not to be a problem, but I can not figure out the images. Also I cant find anything on shuffling images in a list without repeating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ you can make it even easier than a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16828069/80274) to shuffle an IEnumerable (which an array is). It is as simple as

```
var shuffledList = sourceList.OrderBy(_ => rng.Next());
```

where `rng` is a [random number generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) (be sure to implment `Random` [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)).

Your code would look something like this

```
private void Foo()
{
    Image[] icons = { image12, image9, image11, image12, image10, image9, image11, image1,  image12, image9, image11, image10, image12, image9, image10, image11, image9, image10, image12, image11 };
    var shuffeledIcons = icons.OrderBy(_ => rng.Next()).ToArray();

    createBoard(shuffeledIcons);
}

private void createBoard(Image[] icons)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: The caveat is that it requires `O(n ln n)` running time because it relies on sorting. Fisher-Yates is `O(n)`. It might not matter for 20 items, but it's good to know the difference.

Comment: This is what I needed. I didnt even notice this while I was trying the first response. Every time I run it it does exactly what I wanted, no repeating.  I dont know what I did wrong on the other one but I couldnt get it to stop repeating this one doesnt.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just shuffle the array and then iterate through it? It's quite simple; here's an implementation of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), which shuffles the array with just one pass:

```
void Shuffle(Images[] images) {
   for (int i = 0; i < images.Length - 1; i++) {
      int j = rnd.Next(i, images.Length);
      Image temp = images[j];
      images[j] = images[i];
      images[i] = temp;
   }
}
```

Then just call `Shuffle` and go through the array

```
Images[] icons = { ... };
Shuffle(icons);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   newicon[i] = icons[i];
```

Comment: I read up on that but i am fairly new to C# still and I don't know how to take that out put and use it on the next step createboard(newicon[0], newicon[1], newicon[2], newicon[3], newicon[4], newicon[5], newicon[6], newicon[7], newicon[8], newicon[9], newicon[10], newicon[11], newicon[12], newicon[13], newicon[14], newicon[15], newicon[16], newicon[17], newicon[18], newicon[19]); createboard basically takes 20 images and puts them in their place,  I use a function with that many arguments? because I have to createboards for many different outcomes

Comment: What you would do is shuffle the list then just take the first 20 items from the list.

Comment: @user2296611 Well, I don't know what you mean by all those newicons, and it's outside the scope of this question. If you need more help and it's appropriate according to the guidelines, post a new question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have the `createboard` method take an array as an input? Instead of having to send every single element individually.

Comment: It still repeats but I get what your saying by out of the scope of the question so ill keep looking it still puts me in the right direction thanks

Comment: What do you mean it still repeats, if you did it correctly no two items in the array should show up twice unless you put it in there twice.

Comment: @Snixtor good point after I typed copied all that earlier and added the comment i started to change it to take the array instead of one at a time

Comment: @scott after I chanaged it to take an array instead of individual images I ran it 3 times for some reason what im getting is like this:   firsttime: 10 image10, 1 image9, 2 image11, 5 image12, 2 image1       secondtime: 8 image10, 6 image9, 5image11, 1 image1, no image12     thirdtime:  10 image9, 7 image11, 2 image10, and 1 image5, no image1

Comment: I have no clue what you are typing means. You will need to post a new question and give details of what is going wrong.